# How is 得 used in 只有懂得节制欲望的人...？

Tags: grammar

I have always known 得 as an adverb. For example 跑得很快 ，run quickly or run very fast. The following sentence

> 只有懂得节制欲望的人，才能享受到人生的真正乐趣

means "Only a person that understands (how to) control his desires can achieve true happiness." However, I don't understand the use of 得 here. I think I would have written it without the 得. Or is 懂得 a special phrase?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/2742/798).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 懂得, [得 is pronounced **dé** and means "gain" or "obtain"](http://www.zdic.net/z/19/js/5F97.htm), as in the first definition:

> 1. 获取，接受：～到。～失。～益。～空（kòng）。～便。～力。～济。心～。

That is, 懂得 means "to obtain understanding".

The meaning you were referring to is a different use of the same character, and is pronounced **de** (neutral tone):

> 2. 用在动词或形容词后的连接补语，表示效果或程度：跑～快。香～很。

It is true that in your example, the 得 can be omitted without loss of meaning, but it is used to improve the rhythm of the sentence, as the emphasis is on the "懂得".

Comment: I didn't realized it was used in that meaning. Thank you very much.

Comment: Isn't it pronounce déi? At least, that's what I read in my textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, “懂得” is a phrase which means “ understand”. And “得” usually is a structural particle , it is usually used in :“verb + 得+ adjective” structure, which expresses the comment or result of the verb, like: 跑得快  “快” is the comment of “跑”.

Answer (score 0):

懂得 here means "to have understood". 懂 means "to understand"